# Calculations in Vector Register

Tags: compiler, hardware

How do vector registers work in terms of calculations and alloting data to them ?
Is there a detailed reference available somewhere explaining how vector registers work and how data is fetched from them ?

Comment: Are you asking how to write programs using vector registers, or how a CPU designer implements vector registers in the hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are machine architecture reference manuals put out by [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/#manuals), which document (among  many other things) exactly how vector registers and instructions in modern x86-style processors work.

[ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp) has comparable documentation for their architecture and its associated vector processing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the earliest vector registers was the H/L register pair. I think that dates back to the 8080, perhaps the 8008. In the end, a vector register is nothing very special. Instructions still need to specify input register(s), output register(s), and operations. On a silicon level, it means that one operation is dispatched multiple times with different registers, usually in parallel.